# From a wave to a particle... what type of observation exactly?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have a simple question that I have not been able to find an answer to.

I understand that a wave function can be caused to collapse merely by observing. If that is not accurate, please educate me.

My question is simple but the answer may not be.
"What is meant by 'observing'?". 
Does the "observer" require some level of intelligence? Can a simple bug observing a wave function cause it to collapse? Can a non-living thing (camera, etc.) cause a wave function to collapse when it turns its lens or other "observing" structure toward the wave? Or does it have to actually capture an image? Etc..

Any clarity to my confusion is gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Quantum theory models the physical properties of particles by assigning each particle a function of space and time known as its wavefunction. The wavefunction represents, among other things, the probability of a particle being localised in a given area. Wherever the magnitude of the wavefunction is zero, the probability of the particle being in that area is zero; the greater the magnitude of the wavefunction in a given area the greater the probability of finding the particle there.

The wavefunction associated with a particle changes as a consequence of interactions with other particles. There is considerable debate about the mechanism involved here, with different interpretations of quantum theory viewing these changes in different ways. In the 'Copenhagen' interpretation, discontinuous changes to the wavefunction can be known as a 'collapse' or 'quantum jump', depending on the nature of the change. The term 'collapse' is most naturally used where a wavefunction that began as very spread becomes much more localised. The cause of such collapses is an interaction between particles. For example, an electron landing on a photographic plate might be absorbed, or cause ionisation. There is absolutely no requirement whatsoever for an 'observation' or 'measurement' to be performed in order for an interaction to trigger a collapse, although in studying such interactions they often are.

Comment: Thank you. This is an excerpt from researchers at the Weizmann Institute of Science that seems to indicate that an "observer" is required. If you can reconcile this report with your statement that no observer is required, I would appreciate it: "...interference can only occur when no one is watching. Once an observer begins to watch the particles going through the openings, the picture changes dramatically. Scientists used a tiny electronic detector that can spot passing electrons. Apart from "observing" the electrons, the detector had no effect on the current."

Comment: Hi Charlie, the excerpt is just poorly worded. By 'when no one is watching' what they mean is 'when no attempt is made to identify the path of particles creating the interference patterns'. I am afraid the WIS is guilty of dumbing down an explanation to the point at which it borders on misleading nonsense.

Comment: Thank you, Marco... is it possible/likely that the "particle/wave" is in both states all the time and does not really collapse from wave to particle?

Comment: Hi Charlie. That's the million dollar question. I suggest you look up interpretations of quantum theory, on wikipedia for example. There are several competing ideas about the nature of the 'reality' that is so accurately modelled by the mathematics of quantum theory.  There aren't enough characters allowed in comments to do the topic justice! You might find it interesting to read articles by physicists such as David Bohm or Louis de Broglie, whose ideas contrasted with the views of Niels Bohr.